# Python recv Loop

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x

I am try to display data that is sent over a socket via an iteration from a loop.  The way I have it at the moment isn't working on the Admin client.  What should I do to fix my loop?  Thank you

Admin thread in the server -

```
def HandleAdmin(adminSocket,):
    global addressList

    (c,a) = adminSocket.accept() 

    ts = ssl.wrap_socket(c, certfile="5cc515_server.crt",
                             keyfile="5cc515_server.key",
                             server_side=True,
                             cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
                             ca_certs="5cc515-root-ca.cer")

    if ts.recv(80).decode() == 'Hello\r\n':

        ts.send('Admin-Greetings\r\n'.encode()) 

    if ts.recv(80).decode() == 'Who\r\n':
         for i in addressList:
            ts.send(i.encode())
    ts.close()
    return
```

Admin Client

```
import ssl
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

ts = ssl.wrap_socket(s, certfile="100298750.crt",
                        keyfile="100298750.key",
                        ca_certs="5cc515-root-ca.cer")

ts.connect(('127.0.0.1', 4001))

ts.send("Hello\r\n".encode())

if ts.recv(80).decode() == "Admin-Greetings\r\n":

    print("The players currently online are:\n")
    ts.send("Who\r\n".encode())

    loop = True
    try:
        while(loop == True): 
            if (ts.recv(1000) != Null):
                print(ts.recv(1000).decode())
            else:
                loop = False
                ts.close() 
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: "isn't working" isn't descriptive.  What is the expected output vs. actual output, including full tracebacks if an exception occurs?

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is that you try to do `!= Null`, which will raise a `NameError` as Null is not valid in python, it's `None`. You don't see that error because of the raw except. You should only except the errors you are actually expecting.

In addition to that, `recv` doesn't return None when there is not data or the connection is closed, it returns an empty string.

Then in your loop you call `recv` twice, throwing away the result of the first call after the comparison. A better way to write your loop would be:

```
try:
    data = ts.recv(1000)
    while data:
        print(data.decode())
        data = ts.recv(1000)
except IOError as e:
    pass
finally:
    ts.close()
```

Or, if you want a more pythonic solution, use a function iterator with the empty string as sentinel:

```
from functools import partial
for data in iter(partial(ts.recv, 1000), b''):
    print(data.decode())
```